# Bash BG Process in Subshell: Display Output and Also Pipe to Command (Docker CMD Startup Shell Script)

Tags: sql-server, bash, shell, docker, dockerfile

## Direct Question

I am starting a command in a subshell, in the BG. How can I pass the output to both a FG process, as well as displaying it on-screen?

```sh
( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started"
```

This command works, but I cannot see the output of `sqlserver` on-screen.

**It is critical that the script waits wait for `sqlserver` to print `"Service Broker manager has started"` before proceeding.**

## Use Case and Source Code

This is the current setup. Files are abbreviated.

```
--- Dockerfile

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
CMD ["/bin/bash", "dockerrun.sh"]
```

```sh
--- dockerrun.sh

# start DB and wait for it to be up.
( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started"

# restore the DB from backup file
~/sqlpackage/sqlpackage #args

# keep this script running, otherwise Docker will stop the container.
while sleep 1000; do :; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the user informed, you can use `tee` to copy all the output to stderr:

```
( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr | tee /dev/stderr & ) |
    grep -q "Service Broker manager has started"
```